# call react webpack.js from outside.js to add items to list in react component

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, cefsharp, reactjs.net

I am using react to generate static js for wpf application. I have java script class that communicate with c#.

I need to add items to react components from outside js. I do not know how should I call a function inside babel generated js from outside js.

Example:

C# call outside.js to add items

outside.js

function BindText(messages)
{

//need to pass items to component inside site-webpack.js

}

react babel generated js

site-webpack.js

//render componets

I need to call component inside site-webpack.js from outside.js